# Pull Payments details from Stripe API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, stripe-payments

I am creating a WordPress plugin, and trying to pull **payments details from stripe API** done via third party. I have tried everything mention in this code but I am not able to pull data of Payments from stripe.

[image]

**I need to fetch payment details from stripe API**

https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers?lang=php

I have tried payouts *\Stripe\Payout::all()* but getting empty object

Here is my code:

```
namespace wpmember;

class WPMember
{
    public function __construct()
    {       
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page') );                                         
    }


    public function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page() 
    {
        add_menu_page(
            'Custom Menu Title',
            'custom menu',
            'manage_options',
            'custom-menu',
            $this->connect_stripe()
        );

    }

    public function connect_stripe()    
    {            
        require ( PLUGIN_DIR . 'vendor/autoload.php');  
        //echo PLUGIN_DIR . 'vendor/autoload.php';
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxx");
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("xxxx");      

        $customers = \Stripe\Customer::all(["limit" => 3]);
        $products  = \Stripe\Product::all(["limit" => 3]);
        $subscriptions = \Stripe\Subscription::all(['limit'=>3]);
        $orders = \Stripe\Order::all(["limit" => 3]);
        $allpayouts = \Stripe\Payout::all(["limit" => 3]);
        $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::all(["limit" => 3]);
        //$payout = \Stripe\Payout::retrieve($allpayouts->data[0]->id);
        $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::all(["limit" => 3]);        

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($subscriptions);
        echo "</pre>";
    }   


}
```

Comment: it would be great if you update your question with the error description you're getting now

Comment: There is no error, I need to pull transaction/payment data as shown in image. Hope you read my question carefully.

Comment: heh :) I hope you read my comment carefully. If there is no error you're getting the expected results, so what's the question?

Comment: @alexey I have added some more info for your clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be fetching `Payouts` which are according to the [Stripe API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts) are the transfers from your Stripe account to your bank account. Which do not seem to be `Charges` object you showed on your screenshot or `Transfer` objects that could be fetched with `\Stripe\Transfer::all()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you can get the payment details:**

```
require ( PLUGIN_DIR . 'vendor/autoload.php');    
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("pk_test_VNbKcUGTqFIlyfIwFgizNx8h");
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_7VbuCbiZsDZjDHHlOtHeCqo7");         

$charges = \Stripe\Charge::all(["limit" => 3]);
print_r($charges);
```